# How to surround an html element with another tag using lxml in Python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, lxml

What I want to do is something like this. In my page I have an html document which has this tag

```
<p class="pretty">
Some text
</p>
```

And I want to replace it with

```
<blockquote>
    <p>
    Some Text
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

I can strip the class of the tag using `tag.attrib.pop('class')` but I am unable to get how to wrap another html tag around a particular tag.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: basic workflow: remove `tag` from parent (-> getparent), insert new `blockquote` element, add `tag` as a child to the newly created `blockquote` element. I'm sure you are able to work out the details yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are thinking it the wrong way: you cannot wrap an element around another. What you need to do is to copy the contents of the `<p>` into a variable, delete the `<p>` element, create a `<blockquote>` element into where the `<p>` element used to be and then add the contents of the `<p>` element into the `<blockquote>`.

Comment: Yes I was trying to approach the problem the wrong way. Thanks for the help, I can figure it out from here